# Uploading to MEDIA_URL instead of referencing static image

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have some default images stored in my static folder that we use for migrations. I reference these when deploying new features in order to batch create a large number of icons:

```
            # Set Icon
            icon_path = finders.find(my_path)
            if icon_path:
                icon_file = open(icon_path, "rb")
                icon = File(icon_file)
            else:
                raise Exception("Icon file not found.")
            obj.icon = icon
```

One thing I've noticed with this method is that the saved icon references the static folder URL instead of referencing my S3 MEDIA_URL (configured with django-storages). I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing that could be causing this to happen, because when I upload an image and set it the same way from a DRF serializer it goes to S3 instead.

Comment: Have you tried setting the filename manually in `icon = File(icon_file, name="/my/location/icon.png")`?